# How can I center two TextViews vertically within a Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` (that I am not married to) and two `TextView`s.  I would like the bottom of the first `TextView` to line up with the center of it's parent, and the top of the second `TextView` to line up with the center of it's parent.

[image]

I put a green line in the picture above at the (vertical) center of the parent.  The `TextView`s are currently in exactly the right spot, but I did this as I will describe below with margin's and aligning them to the parent and knowing the parent's size.

For various reasons I can't use just one `TextView` and center it.  Also I don't know the height of the parent, so I can't align each to the top/bottom of the parent and margin them down/up to center them.

I also tried having another `View` that takes up half the height and be `invisible`, but `layout_height` doesn't take percents (or at least it gave me errors).

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Should I just put the two `TextView`s inside another layout and have that center itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161456/vertically-centering-two-textviews-in-a-relativelayout/48880191#48880191

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a 0-height view that is centered in its parent and serves as an anchor. (Use the attribute `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for this.) Position one text view above the anchor and the other below the anchor.

Comment: Brilliant, 0 height, instead of 50%... Very clever.  Thanks

Comment: see my answer no need to create new textview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161456/vertically-centering-two-textviews-in-a-relativelayout/48880191#48880191

Comment: @blackHawk - True, I'm creating a new view, but what new textview are you talking about? Also, the solution you posted won't work here because, as OP pointed out in the question, the height of the parent isn't known at coding time, so it's impossible to know what margins to use to get the correct vertical centering.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem before by using a vertical LinearLayout with the two TextViews inside it.

ps.: the Android Design Guidelines http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html specific points out to `Don't use right-pointing carets on line items`. It might not be a line item that you're doing, but in case it is, just to point it out.

Comment: Thanks, that will totally work.  I am not sure which is worse adding an empty view as an anchor or wrapping more layouts in there...  Also appreciate the comment on the carets.  I just noticed this last week in their design guidelines.

Comment: Ignoring the comment re. caret usage, how was the problem of centering the textViews in the LL actually solved?

Comment: @greg7gkb - The LL height is set to `wrap_content` and the LL is then centered vertically in the parent `RelativeLayout`. This aligns the midpoint of the block of two `TextView`s rather than the baseline. It's the option that OP had suggested in the last line of the question.