# Vertically centering two TextViews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

#### What's Happening

I am writing a PopupWindow containing two TextViews, where the second TextView should be centered vertically in the popup, and the first TextView should be directly above it.

The problem is that the RelativeLayout seems to be treating the two TextViews as a single element, and vertically centering the *middle* of them. I want the lower TextView to be the one centered, though, and the upper one to be resting just above it (hence the `android:layout_above="@id/first_name"`).

#### XML Layout

Note the apparently unnecessary LinearLayout there because the RelativeLayout refused to completely vertically fill the screen (the PopupWindow is using `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Christopher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/first_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Java Activity

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<fragment name>,
                                        <parent object>,
                                        false);
final PopupWindow pwindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            true);
pwindow.setTouchable(true);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

}, 100L);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sushil said, you can probably remove your `LinearLayout` completely. The following fix should work; if it does, try removing the linear layout as well.

The issue here is the `android:gravity="center"` on the `RelativeLayout`. If you remove that, you can get the placement you desire:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: It was the gravity, you're right! I replaced `android:gravity="center"` on the RelativeLayout with `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` on the child elements and everything lined up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your Linearlayout simply. Right now your textview are child views of Relativelayout which is a child view to LinearLayout.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Christopher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/first_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/inv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/invfam"
                    android:textColor="#f5f5f5"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/promo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/inv"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Enjoy an additional 15 AED off your first video consultation. Sign up for a Health at Hand account and you will be credited 30 AED as a new user plus an extra 15 AED! #feel better today"
                    android:textColor="#f5f5f5"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```